# Mutable named tuple with default value and conditional rounding support

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code to create a mutable namedtuple. based my understand I can use dataclass to do it. is there a better way to do it or clean up the code?

```
@dataclass
class Price:
    """
    This describes how to map default price value for product
    """
    profit: float = 0.5
    cost: float = 0.1
    sale: float = 25.0

    def round(self, n: float):
        if n < 1:
            return round(n, 2)
        elif n < 100:
            n = round(n / 1)
        elif n < 1000:
            n = round(n / 5) * 5
        elif n < 10000:
            n = round(n / 50) * 50
        else:
            n = round(n / 500) * 500
        return n

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        rate = kwargs.get('rate', 1)
        for k, v in asdict(self).items():
            if k != 'sale':
                v = self.round(v * rate)
            v = kwargs.get(k) or v
            setattr(self, k, float(v))

#run test
p = Price()
p.update(rate=1) #p = Price(profit=0.5, cost=0.1, sale=25.0)

p = Price()
p.update(**{sale=450}, **dict(rate=0.9073)) #p = Price(profit=0.45, cost=0.1, sale=450.0)

p = Price()
p.update(**{sale=800}, **dict(rate=301.377)) #p = Price(profit=150.0, cost=0.1, sale=800.0)

p = Price()
p.update(rate=301.377) #p = Price(profit=150.0, cost=0.1, sale=7550.0)

p = Price(0.0, 0.5, 50.0)
p.update(rate=1) #p = Price(profit=0.0, cost=0.5, sale=50.0)

p = Price(0.0, 0.5, 50.0)
p.update(**{sale=600}, **dict(rate=0.9073)) #p = Price(profit=0.0, cost=0.5, sale=600.0)

p = Price(0.0, 0.5, 50.0)
p.update(**{sale=1200}, **dict(rate=301.377)) #p = Price(profit=0.0, cost=0.5, sale=1200.0)

p = Price(0.0, 0.5, 50.0)
p.update(rate=301.377) #p = Price(profit=0.0, cost=0.5, sale=15000.0)
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using python's built-in ``round`` function or ``Decimal`` class?

Comment: It's fairly clear what you mean by this question, although there are some terminology issues. Tuples by definition are immutable.

Answer (score 13):

In short:

- `dataclass` is the right thing to use as a mutable named tuple. It's basically custom-built to be a great version of that idea.
- [Use `decimal.Decimal` for any financial numbers](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html).
- Don't re-implement `round`. [There's a built-in version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) that behaves in [nice, configurable ways with the Decimal object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial).
- Not sure what the `p.update(**{sale=600}, **dict(rate=0.9073))` is all about, just use `p.update(sale=600, rate=0.9073)` (except with Decimals)

Comment: what should I use build-in `round` version ? based on the logic of round I have?

Comment: Because the builtin version does all yours does, and is tested against all manner of edge cases that yours is not. And if it ever becomes important, it's also faster. So you can just remove the method.

Comment: so how can i use to `round` in the same logic? 102 -> round to 100, 103 -> round to 5 , 1023 -> 1000, 1044 -> 1050

Comment: @jacobcan118 `(Decimal("1206")/10).quantize(Decimal("1"))*10 == Decimal("1210")`. Cumbersome, but surprisingly `quantize` doesn't seem to support rounding integers. I'd love if someone has a simpler solution (not involving `round`, since it converts to floating point).

Answer (score 4):

The line `v = kwargs.get(k) or v` means you cannot use the `update` method to set any of the properties to 0. `get` can take an additional argument for the default value to return. If you change that line to `v = kwargs.get(k, v)`, then `price.update(sale=0)` works as expected.

Comment: Good catch. It is my bug

Answer (score 1):

I suggest some correction and simplification of your `update` method.

**Result:**

```
def update(self, rate=1, **kwargs):
  self_dict = asdict(self)
  self_dict.update(kwargs)

  for k, v in self_dict.items():
    if k != 'sale':
      v = self.round(v * rate)

    setattr(self, k, float(v))
```

**Explanation:**

1. The `rate = kwargs.get('rate', 1)` can be replaced to the `rate=1` keyword argument. It does the same: if the `rate` argument was passed - use it, otherwise use default value `1`.
2. The `v = kwargs.get(k) or v` line doesn't work as you want I suspect. I found two problems:

   - Test your code with these arguments:

     ```
      p.update(sale=450, rate=0.9073, cost=1023)
     ```

     The rate and `round` function wouldn't affect the `cost`. In fact, none of passed keyword arguments will be processed.

     Why? Because the `v = kwargs.get(k) or v` says literally: get keyword argument named `k` from the `kwargs` dictionary and assign it to `v`. If `kwargs` doesn't have such item use `v` (previously processed in the `for` loop). See? If `k` argument was passed it is used directly  - bypassing processing.
   - Also, as was mentioned in other answer, you can't pass `0` as value of keyword argument, because in this case the `kwargs.get(k)` will return `0`, which is interpreted as `FALSE` and the `v` will be used.
3. Both `asdict(self)` and `kwargs` are dictionaries, so we can use the dictionary's update method to replace current `self` values to passed keyword arguments:

   ```
   self_dict = asdict(self)
   self_dict.update(kwargs)
   ```

We can do this at the beginning of function and then use updated, relevant dictionary further.

**Also**, I think the `round` function should be more predictable. Now, it returns `float` in one case, `int` in others...